# ASCII characters in RGB565 format

Tags: c, ascii, rgb, pixel

I want to show some text in a 640*480 screen. Where can I get the codes for ASCII characters in RGB565 format for a C program, such that I can have a natural look-and-feel as a command-line terminal for such a screen.

1- What would be the best width-height for a character?

2- Where can I get the 16-bit hex code (known as Bitmap Font or Raster Font) for each character?

e.g. `const unsigned short myChar[] = {0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004 ...}`

Comment: Nope. He means, simple bitmaps. You know. What's usually known as a raster font

Comment: Yes, sehe is right. Updated the description.

Comment: [bmfont](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) is a nice quick and lean tool I came across recently to generate bitmaps from any font installed on your system. It also saves the glyphs' meta data in a file so you can take the bitmap and the meta data to generate your own font as (C) code.

Answer (score 1):

"... the 16-bit hex code ..." is a misconception. You must have meant 16 *bytes* – one byte (8 pixels) per character line. A 640*480 screen resolution with 'natural' sized text needs 8x16 bitmaps. That will show as 30 lines of 80 columns (the original MCGA screens actually showed only 25 lines, but that was with the equivalent of 640*400 – stretched a bit).

Basic Google-fu turns up this page: https://fossies.org/dox/X11Basic-1.23/8x16_8c_source.html, and the character set comes pretty close to as I remember it from ye olde monochrome monitors:<sup>a</sup>

```
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
...XXXX.........................................................
....XX..........................................................
....XX..........................................................
....XX...XXXXX..XX.XXX...XXX.XX.XX...XX..XXXX...XX.XXX...XXXXX..
....XX..XX...XX..XX..XX.XX..XX..XX...XX.....XX...XXX.XX.XX...XX.
....XX..XX...XX..XX..XX.XX..XX..XX.X.XX..XXXXX...XX..XX.XXXXXXX.
XX..XX..XX...XX..XX..XX.XX..XX..XX.X.XX.XX..XX...XX.....XX......
XX..XX..XX...XX..XX..XX..XXXXX..XXXXXXX.XX..XX...XX.....XX...XX.
.XXXX....XXXXX...XX..XX.....XX...XX.XX...XXX.XX.XXXX.....XXXXX..
........................XX..XX..................................
.........................XXXX...................................
................................................................
```

Since this is a simple monochrome bitmap pattern, you don't need "RGB565 format for a C program" (another misconception). It is way easier to loop over each bitmap and use your local equivalent of `PutPixel` to draw each character in any color you want. You can choose between not drawing the background (the `0` pixels) at all, or having a "background color". The space at the bottom of the bitmap is large enough to put in an underline.

That said: I've used such bitmaps for years but I recently switched to a fully antialiased gray shade format. The bitmaps are thus larger (a byte per pixel instead of a single bit) but you don't have to loop over individual bits anymore, which is a huge plus. Another is, I now can use the shades of gray as they are (thus drawing 'opaque') or treat them as *alpha*, and get nicely antialiased text in any color and over any background.

That looks like this:

[image: antialiased font use]

I did not draw this font; I liked the way it looked on my terminal, so I wrote a C program to dump a basic character set and grabbed a copy of the screen. Then I converted the image to pure grayscale and wrote a quick-and-dirty program to convert the raw data into a proper C structure.

---

<sup>a</sup> Not *entirely* true. The font blitter in the MCGA video card added another column at the right of each character, so effectively the text was 9x16 pixels. For the small set of border graphics – `╔╦╤╕╩` and so on –, the extra column got copied from the rightmost one.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, but apparently that is not what I'm looking for. By 16-bit, I exactly mean 0xyyyy, so, there is no misconception, I guess. My example shows the format I am looking for: `const unsigned short myChar[] = {0x0001, 0x0002, 0x0003, 0x0004 ...}`, the link you sent to me shows 8-bit chars in an array of characters. What I need is 16-bit shorts. I have managed to draw a picture by converting it to RGB565, but still looking for an easy way to show characters.

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism: sorry, you are a bit unclear in your specifications. *One* RGB565 value indeed is a 16-bit `short`, but are you aware that it will only draw *one pixel* as well? So you would need 8*16 `short`s to draw a single character (and then only in a single, fixed color). Hence my suggestion of drawing the bitwise bitmap one bit at a time, in any color (= RGB565 value) you want.

Comment: Thanks Jongware, but is there any reference on how to do so? Or a converter? Can you think of anything?

Answer (score 1):

No the most elegant solution, but I created a bmp empty image and filled it with characters.

Then I used [This tool](https://www.lpcware.com/content/nxpfile/bmp-c-image-conversion-utility) to convert the bmp file to the C bitmap array.
You should then be able to distinguish the characters in your array.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access some type of 16 bit dos mode, you might be able to get the fonts from a BIOS INT 10 (hex 10) call. In this example, the address of the font table is returned in es:bp (es is usually 0xc000). This works for 16 bit programs in Windows dos console mode on 32 bit versions of Windows. For 64 bit versions of Windows, DOSBOX may work, or using a virtual PC should also work. If this doesn't work, do a web search for "8 by 16 font", which should get you some example fonts.

```
INT 10 - VIDEO - GET FONT INFORMATION (EGA, MCGA, VGA)
        AX = 1130h
        BH = pointer specifier
            00h INT 1Fh pointer
            01h INT 43h pointer
            02h ROM 8x14 character font pointer
            03h ROM 8x8 double dot font pointer
            04h ROM 8x8 double dot font (high 128 characters)
            05h ROM alpha alternate (9 by 14) pointer (EGA,VGA)
            06h ROM 8x16 font (MCGA, VGA)
            07h ROM alternate 9x16 font (VGA only) (see #0020)
            11h (UltraVision v2+) 8x20 font (VGA) or 8x19 font (autosync EGA)
            12h (UltraVision v2+) 8x10 font (VGA) or 8x11 font (autosync EGA)
Return: ES:BP = specified pointer
        CX    = bytes/character of on-screen font (not the requested font!)
        DL    = highest character row on screen
Note:   for UltraVision v2+, the 9xN alternate fonts follow the corresponding
          8xN font at ES:BP+256N
BUG:    the IBM EGA and some other EGA cards return in DL the number of rows on
          screen rather than the highest row number (which is one less).
SeeAlso: AX=1100h,AX=1103h,AX=1120h,INT 1F"SYSTEM DATA",INT 43"VIDEO DATA"
```

Comment: I am coding baremetal. The hints were useful though. Thanks. I will look it up

Comment: @TOWI_Parallelism - assuming no copyright issues, the point is that you can grab a set of fonts from a video card, or from a web site. I've used font changing utilities for MSDOS, these days via Virtual PC.